# Camera object is a null pointer

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I Obtained the following code from various tutorials which I am unable to execute, Could someone please help me rectify the mistakes? I tried to debug the app to check why the camera object is returning null but could not understand, Thanks in advance

Video.java

```
public class Video extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private Context myContext;
    private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
    private Camera_Preview mPreview;
    Button s;
    boolean recording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myContext = this;
        initialize();
        capture();

    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        mPreview = new Camera_Preview(myContext, mCamera);

        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);




    }

    private void capture() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (recording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the mediaRecoder object
            Toast.makeText(Video.this, "Video Captured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            recording = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (!prepareMediaRecorder())
            {
                Toast.makeText(Video.this, "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            // work on Ui thread for better performance
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // If there are stories, add them to the table

                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (final Exception ex) {
                        // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");

                    }
                }
            });
            recording = true;
        }

    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mCamera.open();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(200000); // Set max duration 20 sec.
        // mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

}
```

Camera_Preview.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class Camera_Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public Camera_Preview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera == null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    private void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        //method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

}
```

video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.69"
        android:background="#8cc172" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="STOP" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442): Process: com.example.sp_2, PID: 28442
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sp_2/com.example.sp_2.Video}: java.lang.NullPointerException: camera object is a NULL pointer
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: camera object is a NULL pointer
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setCamera(Native Method)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at com.example.sp_2.Video.prepareMediaRecorder(Video.java:94)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at com.example.sp_2.Video.capture(Video.java:64)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at com.example.sp_2.Video.onCreate(Video.java:33)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-13 12:18:42.368: E/AndroidRuntime(28442):    ... 11 more
```

DEBUGGER:

```
mCamera=null
```

Comment: Nowhere in code you assign the Camera to your mCamera variable. The Camera objects should come from the Camera.open() call, but that call is after the code that already uses your mCamera variable (which is null). You have to restructure your code a bit to call Camera.open() before you actually use the mCamera variable in other calls. Also don't forget to add mCamera = Camera.open() and check for exceptions (camera already in use etc.) when you do it or you app will close on exception.

Comment: @Ma3x Could you please tell me where should i call the Camera.open()?
I tried calling in Oncreate() but its giving me failed to connect to camera service

Comment: Anywhere before you actually use the mCamera variable. For example you use it here already `new Camera_Preview(myContext, mCamera);` and here it's still null. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html for the right steps in obtaining the camera and how to check for exceptions.

Comment: @Ma3x Thank you very much I realized the mistake but now its giving me an Error 100 in the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Video.java in the Initialize method you do this:

```
mPreview = new Camera_Preview(myContext, mCamera);
```

However you never actually assign anything to the camera variable. Take a look at this documentation, it should tell you everything you need:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskOpenCamera

Good luck

Comment: Try to google it, if you can't find a solution: Ask another question

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in manifeast file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: You might want to provide at least one or two lines on **why** this should resolve the NPE.

Comment: @Fortran I have added the following lines to my manifest file

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />